# What is the meaning of "Win32-VC9-x64"?

Tags: php

I have a file named php-5.4.23-Win32-VC9-x64.zip. But I don't quite understand the term "Win32-VC9-x64" all together?

Comment: windows, visual c++ 9, and 64-bit.

Comment: Always amusing, that applications carry a 64bit name under MS-Windows. There _still_ is no _real_ 64bit Version of MS-Windows available. Only few libraries have been ported, the core of the system and thus most critical system calls are still 32bit only.

Comment: @arkascha, I suspect the 64-bit applies to memory addressability rather than the use of 64-bit code features throughout the entire Windows code base. The fact that I'm not wasting 75% of my 16G RAM is *more* than enough reason to have a 64-bit variant.

Comment: @paxdiablo Don't get me wrong, the 64bit architecture definitely does make sense and everyone should take advantage of it, where ever possible. I am just amused that of all things the most widely used operating system itself does _not_ really follow that simple logical conclusion. With all it's implications...

Answer (score 1):

It's the 64-bit Windows version built against the Visual C++ 9 (aka 2008) ABI. Extensions will need to be built with the same architecture against the same ABI in order to work with it.